# Orchard CMS record mapping from external Assembly

Tags: orchardcms, nhibernate-mapping, orchardcms-1.8

I have an Orchard CMS module that uses external library. And I need to use some classes from that library as part of Orchard records.
For example, external assembly contains class

```
public class Operation {
    public virtual long Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string OperationType { get; set; } 
}
```

I have to store it in the database, to use it with Orchard IRepository and use it as part of other Orchard CMS records, such as

```
public class HistoryRecord {    
    public virtual long Id { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime Updated { get; set; }
    public virtual Operation Operation { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can do that. You should try to find another way to interact with the external system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get a partial solution, based on `Fluet Configuration`. However, it works only if the classes correspond to the Orchard's naming conventions.
Here it is:

```
public class SessionConfiguration : ISessionConfigurationEvents {
    public void Created(FluentConfiguration cfg, AutoPersistenceModel defaultModel) {
        var ts = new TypeSource(new[] { typeof(OperationRecord) });
        cfg.Mappings(m => m.AutoMappings.Add(AutoMap.Source(ts)
                .Override<OperationRecord>(mapping => mapping.Table("Custom_Module_OperationRecord"))
            ));
    }

    public void Prepared(FluentConfiguration cfg) { }
    public void Building(Configuration cfg) { }
    public void Finished(Configuration cfg) { }
    public void ComputingHash(Hash hash) { }
}


public class TypeSource : ITypeSource {
    private readonly IEnumerable<Type> _types;
    public TypeSource(IEnumerable<Type> types) {
        _types = types;
    }
    public IEnumerable<Type> GetTypes() {
        return _types;
    }
    public void LogSource(IDiagnosticLogger logger) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    public string GetIdentifier() {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```